# Join tables across Cloud Bigtable and BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

is it possible to join 2 tables across Cloud Bigtable and BigQuery? I searched a lot on Google, but couldn't find anything related to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's talk offline.  https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/support has our support channels.  If you have a support package already, that's great.  If not, email us at google-cloud-bigtable-discuss (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-bigtable-discuss)

Answer (score 0):

Since both products are offered as services, you are not able to join 2 tables. You will need to use the API or library layers to export to a common format eg (HBase, Hadoop) and write your own middle-ware to interconnect and join datasets.

Also usually the problem can be resolved with some other techniques - different approach - data duplication - event routing etc...

Comment: Dataflow can do some interesting joins for these two datasources.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis : apologies for this way of asking, but can you plz look into this question related to dataflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362048/specifying-dynamically-generated-table-name-based-on-line-contents

Comment: Nitin, the guy who answered that question is on the Dataflow team.  I'm more familiar with CLoud Bigtable and HBase.